# Can I add another conductor to a 30-amp dryer circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a 30 amp breaker that runs my dryer I want to know am I able to run another wire to that breaker to run a window unit

Comment: Is there no room in the panel for an additional breaker?

Answer (score 2):

No. The 30A breaker is there because dryers draw that amount of current, so adding additional loads to the circuit may cause the breaker to trip.

Comment: Can I do it as a temporary fix and just turn off ac if I need to use dryer till I can get a sub panel ran?

Comment: You probably won't get anyone here to approve such a move. Intentionally creating a scenario that could result in overload is not wise. You know the risk, so don't ask anyone else to sign off on it. Take responsibility yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a second or more wires to any breaker. That is called double tapping. Two hot wires from devices not exceeding the loading % for single pole breaker can be connected together via a wirenut, for example, then a single wire connected to the breaker. In your case specifically, besides the reason I just explained, it can be dangerous to attach a single leg 120vac circuit to one terminal of a double pole 30 amp breaker. It creates an unbalanced load and will not trip properly if overloaded on just one pole. Remember, the two poles are mechanically tied together and trip as a pair.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, every breaker on your panel must feed **one, and only one,** receptacle.

How do common household outlets do it?  **There's an exception for 15 and 20 amp circuits.** This exception does not specify voltage, so feel free to hang several NEMA 6-20 outlets off a single 240V 20A circuit.

By nature any 240V load requires 2 spaces. But you can get ["quad" breakers like this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-Type-BR-BQC-Quadplex-Circuit-Breaker-One-20A-2-Pole-and-One-30A-2-Pole-BQC220230/100112681?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-BASE-PLA-D27E-Electrical%7C&gclid=CO2tvK23g84CFUiGfgodtscDRg&gclsrc=aw.ds) which stack **two** 240V circuits into two spaces in your panel.

[image]

You can also get this same type without the *outer* handle-ties, and use the inner breaker for a 240V circuit and the outers for two 120V circuits.